# Upgrading GNOME 3.4 in 12.04 using individual packages

Tags: gnome, 12.04

How can I install GNOME 3.4 without performing a whole `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

What are the packages I need to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update all packages to the new versions.

Ubuntu 12.04 already contains GNOME3.4 except for a few packages that where updated after the feature lock. Per se, if you update your system you are probably already using it.

If you want the updated packages you need to add the necessary PPA from the GNOME3 team

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 && sudo apt-get update
```

After that you should do an `apt-get upgrade` to install the missing packages.

It makes no sense to install them individually, but, if that is what you want the current missing packages are: *aisleriot, gcr, gnome-disk-utility, gnome-documents, gnome-keyring, gnome-session, libgnome-keyring, seahorse, totem, tracker* and *udisks2*.

Installing them individually will pull out further dependencies for them and so on, in the end it will be the same as just updating your system.